# Can we find an analytic function $f(x)$ whose zeros are the product from the zeros of two given analytic functions?

Tags: roots, analytic-functions

Can we find an analytic function $f(x)$ whose zeros are the product from the zeros of two given analytic functions $g(x)$ and $h(x)$?

Comment: If $a_i$ and $b_i$ are the zeroes, then $f(x)=(x-a_1b_1)(x-a_1b_2)\cdots (x-a_nb_m)$.

Comment: As in "exactly the products and all the products"? Not always. The problem is that the set where the products accumulate can have larger capacity than the limits of each of the two sequences of zeros. This can force the required function to be constant. So, you don't get exactly those zeros.

Comment: @owl I am with you for *sums* of zeroes (e.g., $f(z)=\sin z$ and $g(z)=\sin(\sqrt 2 z)$ would require $h(z)=0$ for a dense subset $\{\,(n+\frac m{\sqrt2})\pi\,\}$ of $\Bbb R$, hence for $\Bbb R$, hence everywhere. For *products* of zeroes and *entire* functions, I don't see what prevents the Weierstraß factorization theorem from being applicable

Comment: The extra assumption is in what you wrote, entire.